# jQ слайдер slick

Tags: jquery, slider

Есть row. В ней 3 колонки: "Описание", "Слайдер", "Форма".

```js
$('.product-name').slick({ 
  autoplay: true, 
  autoplaySpeed: 3000, 
  dots: true, 
  arrows: false });
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="1"> </div>
     <div class="2"> </div>
     <div class="3"> </div>
     <div class="4"> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="product-name">
     <div class="slide_1"> </div>
     <div class="slide_2"> </div>
     <div class="slide_3"> </div>
     <div class="slide_4"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="form"></div>
</div>
```

Центральная колонка это слайдер slick http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. Мне нужно чтобы в то время когда слайдер переключает картинку переключался div с описанием, то есть один отображался,а остальные нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста как это реализовать?

P.S. классы у дивов цифрами просто для примера

Answer (score 2):

Вижу несколько вариантов решения Вашей проблемы:

### 1. Поместить описание в блок слайда

Разверстайте Ваш слайд что бы внутри каждого было описание. Например:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="product-name">
        <div class="slide_1">
            <img crs="..." alt="" class="">
            <p class="">Тут сделайте описание и отформатируйте как Вам удобно.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide_2">аналогично 1-му</div>
        <div class="slide_3">аналогично 1-му</div>
        <div class="slide_4">аналогично 1-му</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### 2. Сделать 2 слайдера, которые будут синхронно листатся

Для этого необходимо связать их и для второго убрать `dots` и `arraws`:

```
$('.product-name').slick({ 
  autoplay: true, 
  autoplaySpeed: 3000, 
  dots: true,
  asNavFor: '.product-description', // свойство для синхронизации
  arrows: false });
```

Пример найдете в [документации](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

### 3. Повесить обработку на событие

```
// On swipe event
$('.your-element').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
  console.log(direction);
  // Здесь менять контент в Вашем блоке form
});
```